# 500 error trying HTTP request from Angular to a service on AWS

Tags: http, proxy, request, cors

**The error:**

"HttpErrorResponse":Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/aws/********/encryptDto2/: 500 Internal Server Error

**The request is only function in Postman but not from Browser.**

This is how I try to call my service from Angular.

jsonEncript:string = "aws/******/encryptDto2/";

encriptDTOService(body:Request) {

```
let encabezado = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
  'Authorization':' Bearer *****'
});
```

return this.httpClient.post(this.jsonEncript, body, { headers: encabezado });
}

**I use a configuration proxy to do HTTP request:**

"/aws":{
"target": "http://**************.amazonaws.com",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite":{
"^/aws":""
},
"changeOrigin": true,
"logLevel": "debug"
}

**NOTE: The CORS policy from my service configuration created with Java in Backedn part contain:**

@Override
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
throws IOException, ServletException {

```
String metodo = req.getRequestURI();

res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, " + "X-Requested-With");
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
res.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

req.setAttribute("requestBody", "");
req.setAttribute("responseBody", "");
```

}